# What does "time at temperature" mean in the maintenance manual of the J79 engine?

Tags: jet-engine, terminology, turbojet, egt

I was reading the maintenance manual of the [General Electric J79](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Electric_J79) and saw these two charts:

[image: chart1]

and

[image: chart2]

What does "time at temperature" mean?

Comment: @mins I don't get why this manual doesn't have any glassory or a part for the parameters which are defined! I think you're right. It should not be that much complex we think. Anyway, I will wait to hear from other fellas.

Comment: The international language for aircraft maintenance documentation is English. In fact the documentation is carefully written in *simple* English so it is easy for non-native speakers to understand. Anyone who claims they are an "Aerospace engineer" *should* be able to read and understand these graphs.

Comment: @alephzero I don't agree with you. I myself is an aerospace engineer and this is the first time that see a maintenance manual. I can guess something about these new parameters but I'm not sure so I need to ask. Aerospace engineering is not just turbine engines. It's a broad field and being familiar with English cannot help that much. Based on your ideology, then all the native speaker could become a technician of jet engine by reading a manual.

Comment: @alephzero: To add to Roh's response, your comment is only valid if said engineer works in intl civil aviation maintenance (3 variables that need to be met).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means the time the engine has been operating at the indicated Exhaust Gas Temperature (EGT).  These are limitation graphs for startup and running to prevent thermally damaging the hot section of the engine during a hot start.  It’s the chief vulnerability of a jet or other aviation gas turbine engine - they’re pretty robust and reliable, but don’t ever, ever, EVER overheat them during start up.

Comment: Sorry I'm not a native speaker but don't get this part "the engine has been operation". You meant "the engine has been operated"? and another question, it looks based on the first graph the temperature below 700 C is safe and based on the second graph, the temp. below 630 is safe. Why are they different? why not e.g. 630 for the two graphs?

Comment: Well you don't never ever want to overheat the engine in **any** phase of operation. Start is no different, it is easier to overheat them at start though. @Roh I edited for more comprehensible term "running". The reason for different temperatures is, that during startup short exceeding of higher temperatures is not as critical as engine parts are not heated yet. So even the exhaust is hot, the engine and its parts are not as hot yet. Also, during start there is not as much load on engine parts (it's basically at idle).

Comment: @Roh Read the labels on the graphs. The first graph is about engine startup. The second graph is about all conditions *except* startup. Also, note the time axis is seconds on the first graph and minutes on the second graph. The second graph also says "indicated temperatures above 750 for a maximum of *three seconds* are acceptable.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

It means duration (time [spent] at). As an example, above are three durations at which the engine was run at 800°C:

- t1: troubleshooting will be needed (0–90 s)
- t2: depending on the model, engine to be returned for inspection of the nozzle (45–90 s)
- t3: engine to be returned for intermediate maintenance (over 90 s)